# Replace tag title from <img> with original-title

Tags: html, image

I want to change title tag from img with origina-title

example:

from `<img src="/img.jpg" title="image"/>`

to `<img src"/img.jpg" original-title="image"/>`

Comment: Are you already using jQuery?

Comment: You want to, effectively, rename the attribute?

Comment: Since `original-title` isn't an official HTML attribute in any HTML spec, you should (assuming the attribute name is your choice) follow the custom `data-*` attribute name scheme and call it `data-original-title`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the attribute of the element, depending on if you're using jQuery or not:

jQuery: https://api.jquery.com/attr/

No library: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.setAttribute

Answer (score 0):

Vanilla JS version:

```
var i = document.getElementById("myImage");
var t = i.getAttribute("title");
i.setAttribute("data-original-title",t);
i.removeAttribute("title");
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/G5QWC/

---

jQuery version:

```
var i = $("#myImage");
i.prop("data-original-title",i.prop("title")).removeProp("title");
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/G5QWC/1/

---

Note that I replaced `original-title` with `data-original-title`. The latter is valid HTML5, as found in [the spec](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#custom-data-attribute).

Comment: But my image don't have id, I have another solution?

Comment: If you can't add a `class`, you can use `var i = $("img");` instead. But be warned that this will affect EVERY img element on the page.

Comment: Doesn't work! in this code replace string with word undefinited example title="undefinited"

Comment: @Alex That means that the `title` attribute wasn't defined in your HTML up front like you showed in your question.

Comment: It are definited! please help me! my site is djslife.net!

Comment: Can you include a working example of your issue here?